# Amazon S3 .NET Core how to upload a file

Tags: amazon-s3, asp.net-core

I would like to upload a file with Amazon S3 inside a .NET Core project. Is there any reference on how to create and use an AmazonS3 client? All i can find in AmazonS3 documentation for .Net Core is this(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-netcore.html) which is not very helpfull.

Comment: @LP13 i have seen a question of yours so i think that u could be helpfull on my question.

Comment: What do you mean on how to upload a file? Uploading a file to AWS/S3 is same, independent of which language you use. It's a Restful API and works with pure HTTP. So any web client in any programming language or environment will work, even stuff like curl from command line. A simple Google query ends up [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpREST.html)

Comment: In .NET Framework it worked fine with AWSSDK. In .NET Core i sould intstall it as middleware and when i tried, nothing worked properly.

Comment: And why not using the AWSSDK? It [works](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.S3/) with .NET Core since it supports `portable-net45+win8` target (PCL for desktop + Windows RT/Mobile), which is compatible with .NET Core (unless it has native dependencies). And if not you can still use the rest api. Also you said you tried middleware, but have posted no code. You should make it clear that you put some efforts and what you tried

Answer (score 44):

I did using IFormFile, like this:

(You need to install `AWSSDK.S3`)

```cs
public async Task UploadFileToS3(IFormFile file)
{
    using (var client = new AmazonS3Client("yourAwsAccessKeyId", "yourAwsSecretAccessKey", RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
    {
        using (var newMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.CopyTo(newMemoryStream);

            var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
            {
                InputStream = newMemoryStream,
                Key = file.FileName,
                BucketName = "yourBucketName",
                CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
            };

            var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);
            await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See my answer, SDK is changed recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865601/amazon-s3-net-core-how-to-upload-a-file/60867277#60867277

Comment: That was really helpful. In addition, I had to include `binaryMediaTypes` in the serverless.yml file in order to configure API Gateway to support media types (e.g uploading file from a form), otherwise the data will be corrupted. Thanks Tiago!!!

Comment: is it possible to upload a file to s3 without SDK, I mean is there any API which we can directly use in .net application to upload file?

Answer (score 17):

For simple file uploading in a .netcore project, I followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads).

After finishing the simple file upload procedure, I followed the documentation on [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html) and [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpNET.html) links, which were very helpful. Following two links were also helpful for a quick start.

1. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/blob/master/ConsoleSamples/AmazonS3Sample/AmazonS3Sample/S3Sample.cs
2. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/fileupload-to-aws-s3-using-asp-net/

This was my final code snippets in the controller for file upload (I skipped the view part, which is elaborately explained in the link shared above).

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public IActionResult UploadFiles(List<IFormFile> files)
{
     long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

     foreach (var formFile in files)
     {
           if (formFile.Length > 0)
           {
                var filename = ContentDispositionHeaderValue
                        .Parse(formFile.ContentDisposition)
                        .FileName
                        .TrimStart().ToString();
                filename = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + $@"\uploads" + $@"\{formFile.FileName}";
                size += formFile.Length;
                using (var fs = System.IO.File.Create(filename))
                {
                     formFile.CopyTo(fs);
                     fs.Flush();
                }//these code snippets saves the uploaded files to the project directory

                 uploadToS3(filename);//this is the method to upload saved file to S3

            }
      }

      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Library");
}
```

This is the method to upload files to Amazon S3:

```
        private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
        private AmazonS3Client _s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.EUWest2);
        private string _bucketName = "mis-pdf-library";//this is my Amazon Bucket name
        private static string _bucketSubdirectory = String.Empty;

        public UploadController(IHostingEnvironment environment)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = environment;
        }


        public void uploadToS3(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new
                    TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest2));

                string bucketName;


                if (_bucketSubdirectory == "" || _bucketSubdirectory == null)
                {
                    bucketName = _bucketName; //no subdirectory just bucket name  
                }
                else
                {   // subdirectory and bucket name  
                    bucketName = _bucketName + @"/" + _bucketSubdirectory;
                }


                // 1. Upload a file, file name is used as the object key name.
                fileTransferUtility.Upload(filePath, bucketName);
                Console.WriteLine("Upload 1 completed");


            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s3Exception.Message,
                                  s3Exception.InnerException);
            }
        }
```

This was all for uploading files in Amazon S3 bucket. I worked on .netcore 2.0 and also, don't forget to add necessary dependencies for using Amazon API. These were:

1. AWSSDK.Core
2. AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup
3. AWSSDK.S3

Hope, this would help.

Comment: It is victory for Bangladesh. Now girls can answer stack. Well done. Upvoted. Good answer!

Comment: thanks, @LiakatHossain , your words are appreciated :)

Comment: Are you creating the file on your  file system before uploading?

Comment: The file is being stored on the project directory first, after that, it is uploaded to the server from that project directory.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a complete sample for upload a file to Amazon AWS S3 with asp.net core mvc

you can see my sample project in github link:

https://github.com/NevitFeridi/AWS_Upload_Sample_ASPCoreMVC

There was a function for uploading file to S3 using Amazon.S3 SDK in the HomeController.

In this function " UploadFileToAWSAsync " you can find every things you need

```cs
        // you must set your accessKey and secretKey
        // for getting your accesskey and secretKey go to your Aws amazon console
        string AWS_accessKey = "xxxxxxx";
        string AWS_secretKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        string AWS_bucketName = "my-uswest";
        string AWS_defaultFolder = "MyTest_Folder";
      protected async Task<string> UploadFileToAWSAsync(IFormFile myfile, string subFolder = "")
        {
            var result = "";
            try
            {
                var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(AWS_accessKey, AWS_secretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
                var bucketName = AWS_bucketName;
                var keyName = AWS_defaultFolder;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subFolder))
                    keyName = keyName + "/" + subFolder.Trim();
                keyName = keyName + "/" + myfile.FileName;

                var fs = myfile.OpenReadStream();
                var request = new Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = keyName,
                    InputStream = fs,
                    ContentType = myfile.ContentType,
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
                };
                await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(request);

                result = string.Format("http://{0}.s3.amazonaws.com/{1}", bucketName, keyName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = ex.Message;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: is it possible to upload a file to s3 without SDK, I mean is there any API which we can directly use in .net application to upload file?

Comment: Yes of course, you can call their HTTP API (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html) directly, you will probably end up with more code to handle authentication etc thought.

Comment: Don't you need to dispose of FileStream?

Answer (score 5):

Addition to @Tiago's answers, AWSS3 SDK is changed a bit, so here is the updated method:

```cs
    public async Task UploadImage(IFormFile file)
    {
        var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("access", "secret key");
        var config = new AmazonS3Config
        {
            RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUNorth1
        };
        using var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, config);
        await using var newMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        file.CopyTo(newMemoryStream);

        var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
        {
            InputStream = newMemoryStream,
            Key = file.FileName,
            BucketName = "your-bucket-name",
            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
        };

        var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);
        await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest);
    }
```

Comment: is it possible to upload a file to s3 without SDK, I mean is there any API which we can directly use in .net application to upload file?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you copy the file to a memory stream before uploading to S3? Why not just call `file.OpenReadStream()` and pass that stream into the `TransferUtilityUploadRequest`?

Comment: @stevesw good question, i wonder that too

Comment: I was not aware of  `OpenReadStream` method of file, so its better to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Per AWS SDK docs, .Net Core support was added in late 2016.

https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/

So the instructions for uploading files to S3 should be identical to any other instructions for .Net.

The "[getting started" guide for the AWS SDK for .Net](https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/net/) is literally the case you describe of connecting and uploading a file to S3 - and included as a sample project ready for you to run if you've installed the "AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio" (which should be installed with the .Net AWS SDK).

So all you need to do is open visual studio, find their sample S3 project, or [you can look at it here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/ConsoleSamples/AmazonS3Sample/AmazonS3Sample):

```
            // simple object put
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest()
            {
                ContentBody = "this is a test",
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = keyName
            };

            PutObjectResponse response = client.PutObject(request);
```

This assumes you have instantiated an Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client after including the namespace, and configured it with your own credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to install in the `Package Manager Console`:

```
Install-package AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCORE.Setup

Install-package AWSSDK.S3
```

Then you need to have the credentials file in the directory:

```
C:\Users\username\.aws\credentials
```

The credential file should have this format:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=[Write your access key in here]
aws_secret_access_key=[Write your secret access key in here]
region=[Write your region here]
```

I uploaded in [github](https://github.com/dayanrr91/aws-net-core-examples) an example of a basic CRUD in ASP.NET CORE for S3 buckets.

Comment: How to authenticate using SAML? My organization doesn't allow us to use key/secret.

Answer (score 0):

We came across an issue when implementing a High-Level API in a .net core solution. When clients had low bandwidth 3mb/s approx an error was thrown by Amazon S3 (The XML you provided was not well-formed). To resolve this issue we had to make an implementation using the low-level API.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLuploadFileDotNet.html

```
// Create list to store upload part responses.
List<UploadPartResponse> uploadResponses = new List<UploadPartResponse>();

// Setup information required to initiate the multipart upload.
InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initiateRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Key = pathbucket
};

//Add metadata to file 
string newDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");                    

// Initiate the upload.
InitiateMultipartUploadResponse initResponse = await s3Client.InitiateMultipartUploadAsync(initiateRequest);      
int uploadmb = 5;

// Upload parts.
long contentLength = new FileInfo(zippath).Length;
long partSize = uploadmb * (long)Math.Pow(2, 20); // 5 MB         

try 
{
    long filePosition = 0;
    for (int i = 1; filePosition < contentLength; i++) {
        UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest{
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = pathbucket,
            UploadId = initResponse.UploadId,
            PartNumber = i,
            PartSize = partSize,
            FilePosition = filePosition,
            FilePath = zippath
        };

        // Track upload progress.
        uploadRequest.StreamTransferProgress += new EventHandler<StreamTransferProgressArgs>(UploadPartProgressEventCallback);
        // Upload a part and add the response to our list.
        uploadResponses.Add(await s3Client.UploadPartAsync(uploadRequest));
        filePosition += partSize;
    }

    // Setup to complete the upload.
    CompleteMultipartUploadRequest completeRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = pathbucket,
        UploadId = initResponse.UploadId
    };
    completeRequest.AddPartETags(uploadResponses);

    // Complete the upload.
    CompleteMultipartUploadResponse completeUploadResponse = await s3Client.CompleteMultipartUploadAsync(completeRequest);
} 
catch (Exception exception) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("An AmazonS3Exception was thrown: { 0}", exception.Message);

    // Abort the upload.
    AbortMultipartUploadRequest abortMPURequest = new AbortMultipartUploadRequest {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = keyName,
        UploadId = initResponse.UploadId
    };
}
```